# Is there a way to install Ubuntu to my hard drive from a usb thumbdrive that's running ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I want to install Ubuntu (Thats on a flashdrive and is 10 gigs used already) to my hard drive that I just formatted. Is it possible to copy over the current Ubuntu or not?

Comment: Interesting idea, but wouldn't it be much easier for you to simply use the flash drive the same way you would use an Ubuntu live USB flash drive and click the **Install Ubuntu** icon on the desktop to start the Ubuntu installer? First you need to run the command: `sudo apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to copy over the current Ubuntu or not?

Yes it is, but **it is not guaranteed** that it will work as it should.

**Transfer an existing Ubuntu installation to an empty partition with rsync.**

*Linux filesystem is a prerequisite (`ext4` is preferred)*

First create the partition (`ext4` filesystem). Use `gparted` to create a partition in your HDD. Be sure that is equal or even better bigger than your current Ubuntu installation.

Then mount the new ext4 partition under `/mnt` directory. We assume here that is **/dev/sda1**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Now prepare for the last step. My suggestion (it is not a rule) is to close any programs you have open and do not do anything until the end.

```
sudo rsync -aAXv /* /mnt/ --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}
```

When the copy is done,

give an additional command (maybe is not needed, but in any case)

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

**Again**, we assume here that the HDD is the `/dev/sda` drive and the  new created partition (for the Ubuntu transfer) is `/dev/sda1`.

Reboot your PC, set it to boot from the HDD first.

Good Luck.